# The virtual path '/' maps to another application IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, path, iis-7, renderpartial

I call HTML.RenderPartial in Razor take tilde (~) and works fine on VS2015 but when publish on IIS under Default Web Site give that error "The virtual path '/' maps to another application, which is not allowed."

Comment: How do you expect people to be able to help you without seeing any code?

Answer (score 0):

In Razor, you can add Action and Controller by avoiding to put (~), if you want to put the (~) try to put a path to localhost and the path with the full path to work in IIS

Comment: I want to use Html.RenderPartial in Razor and I already put the (~) with the full path to the cshtml file but it gave me the same error. In IIS when I publish as website it works fine but I need it to be ass application under Default web site